# time at the corner of the animation node editor?

Tags: node-editor, animation-nodes

What is the significance of the time displayed at the corner of the animation node editor? Is it the time period of the loop the node editor is executing?

[image]

Comment: What is the Blender version and do you use any addons?

Comment: The blender version is 2.78c and I am seeing this while using the animation nodes addons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time at the corner is the **total execution time of the node tree**. It is usually measured in milliseconds.

Increase the number of divisions in your grid node and you will notice that the time increases because more processing is required.